# scp (secure copy) in lieu of vmware disk-sharing

Tags: sharing, vmware, unix, scp

Booting down the linux VM, removing the share, disabling sharing,

followed by enabling sharing, adding the share, and booting up the linux Vm

finally followed by reinstalling vmware tools

do not make the shared drive appear under /mnt/hgfs.

My question is: I'd like to use old-fashioned scp to copy a tar archive.

On the linux VM: scp FROM/dir/file.tar ~/.

What should FROM be?

Comment: How is networking set up on the VM? Bridged or shared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to connect from Linux back to your Mac you'll need to make sure ssh access is enable on you Mac first. Go to System Settings -> Sharing and make sure the Remote Login option is check.

This dialog will also tell you the the IP address of your Mac and the account name to use to connect. If your Linux VM's network is set to Bridged you can work with your Mac as if it was any other machine on your network. They both have unique IPs in your local network. So:

[image: Setting up remote login via ssh on your Mac]

From a terminal window on your Linux VM you can now do:

```
scp <stuff to copy> <your mac user name that users returned>@<ip address of the active interface>:/path/to/put/stuff/at
```

For example, according to my settings, if I wanted to copy from a terminal window on my Linux VM to my Mac I'd do:

```
scp myfile.txt ian@192.168.1.99:~/tmp/
```

That would put `myfile.txt` from my Linux VM in to `/Users/ian/tmp` on my OS X host OS.

Similarly, from the Linux VM:

```
scp ian@192.16.8.1.99:~/tmp/myfile.txt .
```

Would copy `myfile.txt` from the Mac back to my working directory on the Linux VM.

If you're trying to connect from your Mac to your Linux machine you need to make certain that the [ssh](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/sshd/) daemon is running on your Linux machine. To start sshd, open a terminal on your Linux machine and type:

```
sudo /sbin/service sshd start
```

If it starts correctly you'll see a `[START]` box. If it fails, well, that's a question for https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Now you just need to get the IP address for your Linux VM. At a terminal window on your Linux VM type:

```
ifconfig
```

The `eth0` interface should be your active ethernet interface. Grab it's IP address. That's what you'll use to connect to your Linux VM from a Terminal window on your Mac.

Open a Terminal window on your Mac and type:

```
scp <local file> <username>@<ip address you got above>:~/tmp/
```

to copy the file from your Mac to your Linux VM while you're on you Mac.

Comment: On the Mac I am getting "ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.118 port 22: Connection refused" and on the linux side I get "ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.118 port 22: No route to host".

Comment: Those are the same IP addresses -- which machine does that IP belong to? I'll add some more details to the question.

Comment: On the mac side ifconfig tells me that 192.168.2.118 is active. Does that mean that this is the IP of the linux?

Comment: No. That's the IP address of your Mac. You can run `ifconfig` in a terminal window on your Linux VM to get the IP address of the Linux VM.

Comment: Still having trouble despite the very clear message. On linux /sbin/ipconfig gives me under eth0 some mac-address (six hex separated by colons) but no IP address. Still on linux, now that sharing is on in the Mac's Sharing preferences I am now getting "port 22: Network is unreachable".

Comment: Hmm.. my linux VM is missing something more basic. Even when I try to scp from my account on a server I know is configured properly, I get "ssh: could not resolve hostname".

Comment: Sounds like your VMs network interface isn't configured. What happens if you run `sudo /sbin/service network restart`? Did you download this VM or install it from scratch?

Comment: All is well... This is very nice!